# Response de Symfony cuando envía un error no se muestra correctamente

Tags: php, angular, apache, symfony

una disculpa si el título no se entiende, se aceptan sugerencias.

Tengo una duda conforme al siguiente caso, trabajo con Angular 8 como front-end y Symfony 5 para back-end.

Originalmente, yo usaba Symfony 4.3 con PHP 7.2, uso el Postman para realizar las pruebas de la API. Cuando la API me retorna un error, muestra los detalles de la misma (formato en html).

Cuando actualicé a Symfony 5 con PHP 7.3.9, los errores ya no se muestran correctamente, es decir, puedes observar el error pero con todas las etiquetas html visibles, como si no leyera el html correctamente como antes. Esto mismo sucede al usar la consola de Chrome, (Network > Preview).

Anexo imagen de cómo se ve ahora, antes si se veía correctamente la respuesta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Me faltará alguna configuración para que se muestren correctamente los mensajes?

Gracias, que tengan buen día.

Comment: PHP 4.3.9 y Symfony !?!?

Comment: Symfony lo actualicé de la versión 4.3 a la versión 5.

Comment: Ups, he corregido el texto, es PHP 7.2 a PHP 7.3.9